# half life radioactive substance

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I need help solving this calculus problem and i am really confused about how to work it

> Let $y(t)$ denote the mass of a radioactive substance at time $t$.
>   Suppose this substance obeys the equation : $y′(t)=−16y(t)$.   Assume
>   that, initially, the mass of the substance is $y(0)=M>0$. At what time
>   does half of the mass remain? (Round your answer to $3$ decimal
>   places).

I dont really know where to begin with this problem

Answer (score 2):

You want to determine $t_0$ such that $y(t_0)=\frac{y(0)}{2}$.

Let's find the expression of $y(t)$, we have to solve a first order linear differential equation. So :
$$y(t)=Ke^{-16t},K\in \mathbb{R}$$

We use $y(0)=M$ to evaluate $K$ : $y(0)=K=M$, so $y(t)=Me^{-16t}$.

Let's find $t_0$ : $$y(t_0)=\frac{y(0)}{2}\iff Me^{-16t_0}=\frac{M}{2}\iff e^{-16t_0}=\frac{1}{2} \iff-16t_0=-\ln(2) \\\iff t_0=\frac{\ln(2)}{16} \approx 0.043$$

Answer (score 0):

Going for the solutions of the differential equation:
$$
0 = y'(t) + 16 y(t) = (d/dt) \left( y(t) e^{16 t} \right) \Rightarrow \\
c = y(t) e^{16 t} \Rightarrow\\
y(t) = c e^{-16 t}
$$
where $c$ is some constant. For $t = 0$ we get
$y(0) = c$, so
$$
y(t) = y(0) \, e^{-16 t}
$$ 
We are looking for a $t$ with $y(t) = y(0) / 2$, inserting this into the solution we get
$$
y(0) / 2 = y(0) \, e^{-16 t} \iff \\
e^{16 t} = 2 \Rightarrow \\
16 t = \ln(2) \Rightarrow \\
t = \ln(2) / 16 = 0.04332169878499658\dotsb \approx 0.04
$$